# DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode return null

Tags: html-agility-pack

I want to get the time of this url "https://www.toutiao.com/a6619068128406028804/" with the HtmlAgilityPack, my code is as following:

```
string url = "https://www.toutiao.com/a6619068128406028804/" 
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);

HtmlNode node_time= doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]");
time = node_time.InnerText.Trim();
```

node_time is always being null, how can I get the content of the time tag?

Comment: Have you tried "//" in your path like this HtmlNode node_time= doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//html/body//div[1]//div[2]//div[2]//div[1]//div[1]//span[2]");

Or

you can try fetching the node using unique class of div -article-sub

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the xPath selector, it's the fact that those elements are rendered client side. If you look at the actual initial get request (can do this in chrome/fiddler/ext) you see that those elements are not there. However there is a "articleInfo" json object inside of the "BASE_DATA" json string that is sent back. Normally you want to parse out that string and then deserialize it, then you have a structured object to grab data from. I normally use visual studio paste as classes feature but this seems kind of complicated for that and is mostly outside of the scope of your issue with this.

Also to note the object does get loaded into javascript but you cannot access that with HAP, if  you were using headless browsers you could access that object directly using the execute javascript features.

So basically you can either parse out the json string manually or switch to something like a headless browser where the javascript is actually executed.